# Definition of expectation for non-real-valued random variables

Tags: probability-theory, vector-spaces, expected-value

I have checked many sources for the definition of expectation for non-real-valued random variables. I am interested on the **conditions of the image space** that guarantee the existence of an expectation operator. For example, I have seen definitions of expectation for complex-valued and real-vector-valued random variables, and these work "component by component".

**Question.** I am wondering if there is a general definition of expected value that asks for some conditions about the image space of the random variables and captures all image spaces for which expected values make sense.

So far I have only concluded that the image space must necessarily support *addition* and *scalar multiplication* to be able to define expectation for random variables with finite set of possible outcomes, i.e. $\sum_{i=1}^k P(X=x_i) x_i$. Some other conditions that come to my mind are being a measure space, a metric space and being complete, but I am not sure how are they necessary and if they are sufficient.

Comment: If the image space is a Banach space, you are fine. I don't really know if a strictly more general setting is possible. Search term: Bochner integral.