# Confusion over the definition of "source code" in information theory

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, random-variables, definition, information-theory

This is from Thomas and Cover's textbook, 2nd.

Def. A source code $C$ for a random variable $X$ is a mapping from $\mathcal{X}$, the range of $X$, to $\mathcal{D}^\star$, the set of finite length strings of symbols from a $D$-ary alphabet.

Ok. Then the example immediately following is:

$C(red) = 00$, $C(blue) = 11$ is a source code for $\mathcal{X} = \{red, blue\}$ with alphabet $\mathcal{D} = \{0, 1\}.$

1. What is an "alphabet" and a "symbol" in this definition?
2. Since the range of random variables are subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, then how can $C$ map from blue and red when these are not element of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: 2. Not all random variables are real random variables.

Comment: @GEdgar Could you elaborate or provide ref?

Comment: Not an expert on this subject, but I think I’d define a “$D$-ary alphabet” to be just a set with $D$ elements. In this context, once an alphabet has been introduced, the elements of the alphabet are called “symbols”.

Answer (score 0):

> What is an "alphabet" and a "symbol" in this definition?

In general, an alphabet is the repertoire (the set) of possible values.

In this case, the source can take two values $\{ red, blue\}$ , this would be $\mathcal{X}$, the  source alphabet.

And the code is binary, then the symbols are $\{ 0, 1 \}$, and this is the code alphabet ($\mathcal{D}$).

> Since the range of random variables are subsets of $\mathbb{R}$...

What? No. The range of a random variable can be anything.

Comment: The range of random variable must be $\mathbb{R}$ no? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240673/what-exactly-is-a-random-variable. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3777899/so-what-really-is-a-random-variable

Comment: The range need not be $\mathbb R$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable

Comment: No, the range must not be real. See the first two examples in the most upvoted answer you link. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3777902/312 

It's true than in most applications we deal with real-valued (perhaps multidimensional) random variables (and some concepts like expected value make sense only for them) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4104788/definition-of-expectation-for-non-real-valued-random-variables

Comment: @leonbloy Thanks for the references. But non-real-valued rvs seem to be obscure, no? You could define it but I don't see any real applications arising from them. There also doesn't seem to be a textbook that deals with these rvs.

Comment: "I don't see any real applications arising from them" Well, take information theory :-)
Contrary to other measures like expectation, variance, etc, Shannon entropy does not imply or require a real-valued variable.

Comment: To the contrary, all kinds of signals are complex, QAM, QPSK, etc, and the main focus of information theory is digital communications. The alphabet may be $\{1,-1,i,-i\}$ or other complex sets.